# Parse this string of a JSONObject that contains a JSONArray of JSONObjects

Tags: php, json

I want to parse this string of a JSONObject that contains a JSONArray of JSONObjects

```
Array
(
[Assignments] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ass_name] => Test123
                [class_id] => 2
                [date_assigned] => 2017-08-23
                [done] => false
                [due] => 2017-08-23 13:34:54
                [id] => 10
                [weight] => 65
            )

    )

)
```

I tried using

```
$json = json_decode($testing,true);
echo $json;
```

where $testing is my entire string but $json echos nothing.

Comment: Your string is already array object which you post in question then obviously `json_decode` not works.

Comment: So.. What will work?

Comment: This is not json, is it?

Comment: Check my hint @JavierSalas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example,

**`echo`** => Outputs one or more strings separated by commas

**`print_r`** => Accepts not just strings but other types including arrays and objects, formatting them to be readable

```
$testing = array("Assignments"=>array("ass_name"=>"Test123","class_id"=>"2","date_assigned"=>"2017-08-23","done"=>"false","due"=>"2017-08-23 13:34:54","id"=>"10","weight"=>"65"));

$json = json_encode($testing); //convert array to json
echo $json;

$json1 = json_decode($json,true); //convert json to array
print_r($json1);
```

Comment: This helped my understand my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you.Don't forget to upvote it.@JavierSalas

Comment: @Nidni I upvoted it but this account is too new for it to show.

Comment: No worry.Keep it up.@JavierSalas

Answer (score 0):

Do not use  `echo` for print arrays or objects.

```
$testing = json_encode(
    array(
        'Assignments' => array(
            0 => array(
                'ass_name'      => 'Test123',
                'class_id'      => 2,
                'date_assigned' => '2017-08-23',
                'done'          => false,
                'due'           => '2017-08-23 13:34:54',
                'id'            => 10,
                'weight'        => 65,
            ),
        ),
    )
);

$json = json_decode($testing, true);
echo $json; // prints "Array"
print_r($json); // prints all items in array
```